# SQLite: How to select part of string?

Tags: sqlite, position, substring

There is table column containing file names: image1.jpg, image12.png, script.php, .htaccess,...

I need to select the file extentions only. I would prefer to do that way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR(column,INSTR('.',column)+1) FROM table
```

but INSTR isn't supported in my version of SQLite.

Is there way to realize it without using INSTR function?

Answer (score 9):

below is the query (Tested and verified)
for selecting the file extentions only. Your filename can contain any number of `.` charenters - still it will work

> select distinct replace(column_name, rtrim(column_name,
>   replace(column_name, '.', '' ) ), '') from table_name;

`column_name` is the name of column where you have the file names(filenames can have multiple `.`'s

`table_name` is the name of your table

Comment: very clever solution.

Comment: how to get empty value if there is no dot?

Answer (score 6):

Try the `ltrim(X, Y)` function, thats what [the doc](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) says:

> The ltrim(X,Y) function returns a string formed by removing any and all characters that appear in Y from the left side of X.

List all the alphabet as the second argument, something like

```
SELECT ltrim(column, "abcd...xyz1234567890") From T
```

that should remove all the characters from left up until `.`. If you need the extension without the dot then use `SUBSTR` on it. Of course this means that filenames may not contain more that one dot.

But I think it is way easier and safer to extract the extension in the code which executes the query.

Comment: Thank you. If there are >1 dots then it's better to use rtrim() and then SUBSR(column,(length(column)-length(rtrim())))

Answer (score 0):

Using the json functions as of SQLite version 3.38.0 this can also be achieved.

The nice thing here compared with the `replace(column_name, rtrim(column_name, replace(column_name, '.', '' ) ), '')` approach is you only need to mention `column_name` once.

```
select distinct json_extract(json('{"s":["'||replace(column_name,'.','","')||'"]}'), '$.s[#-1]') from table_name;
```

And here is some comparisons, including handling filepaths with no extensions:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t (fn TEXT);
insert into t values (NULL);
insert into t values ('');
insert into t values ('a');
insert into t values ('abc');
insert into t values ('abc.def');
insert into t values ('abc.d.s.edrs');

SELECT
  fn AS full_filename,
  replace(fn, rtrim(fn, replace(fn, '.', '' ) ), '') AS option_a,
  json_extract(json('{"s":["'||replace(fn,'.','","')||'"]}'), '$.s[#-1]') AS option_b,
  CASE WHEN fn LIKE '%.%' THEN replace(fn, rtrim(fn, replace(fn, '.', '' ) ), '') ELSE NULL END AS option_c,
  CASE WHEN fn LIKE '%.%' THEN json_extract(json('{"s":["'||replace(fn,'.','","')||'"]}'), '$.s[#-1]') ELSE NULL END AS option_d
FROM t;
```

Which, using `.headers on` and `.mode column` , outputs this:

```
full_filename  option_a    option_b    option_c    option_d
-------------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------


a              a           a
abc            abc         abc
abc.def        def         def         def         def
abc.d.s.edrs   edrs        edrs        edrs        edrs
```