# SQLite: isolating the file extension from a path

Tags: sqlite

I need to isolate the file extension from a path in SQLite.  I've read the post here ([SQLite: How to select part of string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909492/sqlite-how-to-select-part-of-string)), which gets 99% there.

However, the solution:

```
 select distinct replace(column_name, rtrim(column_name, replace(column_name, '.', '' ) ), '') from table_name;
```

fails if a file has no extension (i.e. no '.' in the filename), for which it should return an empty string. Is there any way to trap this please?

Note the filename in this context is the bit after the final `'\'`- it shouldn't be searching for`'.'s` in the full path, as it does at moment too.

I think it should be possible to do it using further nested `rtrims` and `replaces`.

Comment: I don't think it is possible in plain SQLite3. However, SQLite3 supports custom functions, which would make it trivial. Which language are you using SQLite3 from?

Comment: I'm using queries interactively within SQLiteStudio.

Comment: http://wiki.sqlitestudio.pl/index.php/User_Manual#Custom_SQL_functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks.  Yes, you can do it like this:

1) create a scalar function called "extension" in QtScript in SQLiteStudio

2) The code is as follows:

```
if ( arguments[0].substring(arguments[0].lastIndexOf('\u005C')).lastIndexOf('.') == -1 )
{
  return ("");
}
else
{
  return arguments[0].substring(arguments[0].lastIndexOf('.'));
}
```

3)  Then, in the SQL query editor you can use

```
select distinct extension(PATH) from DATA
```

... to itemise the distinct file extensions from the column called PATH in the table called DATA.

Note that the PATH field must contain a backslash ('\') in this implementation - i.e. it must be a full path.

Answer (score 0):

To meet this requirement in your question: *"if a file has no extension (i.e. no '.' in the filename), for which it should return an empty string."*

Just add a CASE WHEN LIKE to the statement, like this:

```
select distinct case when column_name like '%.%' then replace(column_name, rtrim(column_name, replace(column_name, '.', '' ) ), '') else '' end from table_name;
```

or more easier to read (same code):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  CASE
    WHEN column_name LIKE '%.%' THEN replace(column_name, rtrim(column_name, replace(column_name, '.', '' ) ), '')
    ELSE ''
  END
FROM table_name;
```